# Docker container exited with code 0 after docker-compose up -d

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I know the question has been asked in various situations, but I'm still stucked despite everything I read on the Internet.

I want to have a script executed after the container "mywebsite" is built and I used `ENTRYPOINT` for that and I know that in normal use, after the `ENTRYPOINT` command is executed, the container "mywebsite" exit. I tried several tricks to avoid exit, unfortunately without success.

In my `DOCKERFILE` I have this :

```
FROM php:7.1.17-apache

[...]    

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /var/www/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/var/www/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Then in my docker-entrypoint.sh I have this :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cd www
chown -R www-data:www-data sites modules themes

exec "$@"
```

And here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  mywebsite:
    build: .
    extra_hosts:
      - "mywebsite.local:127.0.0.1"
    hostname: mywebsite
    domainname: local
    ports:
      - 8088:80
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/www
      - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor
      - ./scripts:/var/www/scripts
    links:
      - database:database
    restart: always
    tty: true
  database:
    image: mysql:5.5.49
    container_name: mysql-container
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - ./www/dumps/mywebsite.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    restart: always
    command: --max_allowed_packet=32505856
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mywebsite
```

When build, all steps are fine, and everything is set properly, but the container  "mywebsite" keep exiting. (The "database" service is running fine)

I haded `tty: true` and `exec "$@"` but none of that works.

Comment: What are you expecting the `exec "$@"` to do? What command should it run?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I don't really know, I saw that in some answers to avoid exit. Also got that from the offical mysql image => https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: The official mysql images have a default command they run. Your image doesn't have that, so your exec is running nothing and immediately finishing.

Comment: Oh ok, actually, the only thing I want to execute after the container is run is : cd www && chown -R www-data:www-data sites modules themes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can end with command like `tail -f /dev/null`

I often use this directly in my docker-compose.yml with `command: tail -f /dev/null`. And it is easy to see how I keep the container running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating my own image from a postgis-image. The problem was that I added an entrypoint. When I removed the entrypoint, build the image again, docker-compose does start my container and postgis was accepting connections.

dockerfile

```
FROM postgis/postgis:12-master

COPY organisation.sql

#ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]  #This was the problem
```

In docker-compose I did not need command's or tty.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mydb:
    image: mydb:latest
    container_name: mytest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
```